# User's data in the Flask's aplication

Tags: python, flask

Where and how should i keep personal data (login and password) of my aplication's user on Flask?

```
def login():
form = LoginForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    flash('Login requested for user {}, remember_me={}'.format(
        form.username.data, form.remember_me.data))


    return redirect('/index')
return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

Comment: This is off-topic. See: [help/on-topic].

Comment: There could be many answers to that. 
Why don't you use some simple plugin such as https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ?

Comment: Database -- [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html) would work fine for this.

Answer (score 0):

take the username, password from the login page and check them against the value in database and if correct then proceed further

```
   from flask_login import login_user
   @app.route('/login', method=['post', 'get'])
    def login():
        form = LoginForm(request.form)
        current_app.logger.info("Hello from the home page!")
        # Handle logging in
        current_app.logger.info("this is form {} {}".format(form, form.username))
        if request.method == "POST":
            current_app.logger.info("post request is made")

            if form.validate_on_submit():
                login_user(form.user)
                flash("You are logged in.", "success")
                redirect_url = request.args.get("next") or url_for("public.dashboard")
                return redirect(redirect_url)
            else:
                flash_errors(form)
        return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

Comment: Application gives me this error:
login_user(form.user)
NameError: name 'login_user' is not defined

Comment: @ИванИванов login_user is method from `flask_login` library, you need to install it in your env

Comment: AttributeError: 'LoginForm' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: @ИванИванов in class LoginForm write inside __init__(self)  self.user

Comment: I can't find this space for pasting  __init__(self) self.user

Comment: opensource your project in github(if possible), let us see and then add  the correct data where you are facing issue